# millisecond date is not returning expected result

Tags: java

For an assignment, I had to code a due date which is 30 days after the invoice date. When I run my program, I'm not getting a correct date. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Code from class that creates and formats due date:

```
// a method that returns the due date
public Date getDueDate()
{
    Date dueDate = new Date(invoiceDate.getTime() +
            (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return dueDate;
}

// a method that returns the formatted due date
public String getFormattedDueDate()
{
    DateFormat shortDueDate  = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    return shortDueDate.format(this.getDueDate());
}
```

Code from main class which calls the getFormattedDueDate:

```
public static void displayInvoices()
{
    System.out.println("You entered the following invoices:\n");
    System.out.println("Number\tTotal\tInvoice Date\tDue Date");
    System.out.println("------\t-----\t------------\t--------");
    double batchTotal = 0;
    int invoiceNumber = 1;
    while (invoices.size() > 0)
    {
        Invoice invoice = invoices.pull();
        System.out.println(invoiceNumber + "\t     " + invoice.getFormattedTotal()
                + "       " + invoice.getFormattedDate()
                + "\t     " + invoice.getFormattedDueDate());

        invoiceNumber++;
        batchTotal += invoice.getInvoiceTotal();
    }
```

Comment: What result did you get?  What result did you expect?

Comment: The invoice date is today and I expected 3/15/12. The date returned is 1/25/12

Comment: A poster on coderanch provided me the answer. I thought I'd add it here in case anyone else has a similar problem. In the calculation which adds 30 days to the invoice date, it should read: "(30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)". I tested it and this indeed worked. I'm not sure what the "L" accomplished but will look it up.

Comment: L forces the literal number to be long instead of int. the expression comes out at 0x9A7EC800 (showing in hex so you can see that top most bit is set) - in an int that is your sign bit, so the expression has "overflowed" and the quick fix is to do it as a long instead of an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's bad to perform date math like that, IMO.  Do this:

```
public Date getDueDate() {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(invoiceDate);
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
   return cal.getTime();
}
```